# What files are necessary for a Cordova app build from a Wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to build a mobile app from my existing wordpress website. I am curious which files I need to include in the assets folder for Cordova? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Cordova must include only html and JavaScript files, WordPress is based on php, but Cordova can't have server side code.

Your only option is to build hosted Cordova App using for example [ManifoldJS](http://manifoldjs.com/).

Comment: +1. You can download content from the server using JavaScript, but it would be a lot of work to integrate with WordPress

Comment: if you can separate client and server part, but I don't think it's possible in WordPress.

Comment: We've built plenty of Cordova apps that pull data from WordPress sites. We either use the official WP-API, or write lightweight API endpoints which return JSON.

Comment: but do you need to create UI for client part?

Comment: yes, found this: http://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-phonegap-app-with-a-wordpress-backend/

Comment: @rnevius, probably you can answer this question better than me